# Why is xcode asking for landscape launch images?

Tags: ios, xcode

Why is xcode asking for landscape launch images?
My app doesn't support landscape in neither iPhone nor iPad
[image]

Comment: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an issue with the xcode beta release

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `Info.plist` reflects the fact that your app doesn't support landscape. It's not enough that none of your view controllers support it. Make sure the "Supported Interface Orientations" in the "Summary" tab for your target only has the portrait orientations selected in both the iPhone/iPod and iPad Deployment Info sections. These sections are equivalent to the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad` keys in `Info.plist`. That is, editing them in the "Summary" tab also edits your `Info.plist` for you.

Comment: I've verified in both the Info.plist and the target general states Portrait. Nowhere does it state landscape

Comment: If this didn't solve your problem you should not mark it as the accepted answer. It's fine to up-vote the answer if you found it useful, but by marking it as accepted people will think that your problem is solved and you might not get any other answers. If the answer did not directly solve your problem but led you to find and fix the problem, then you can mark it as accepted but add a comment to explain what further steps were necessary so that other users with the same issue can follow them. :)

Comment: Too quick on the trigger finger. I've unchecked it.

Comment: I ended up adding the landscape screenshots it wanted, but I still need to figure out why its doing that.

Comment: A clean build might help, and deleting DerivedData. Sometimes Xcode can get confused.